# Create a file .dmg for Mac without certification

Tags: objective-c, macos

How do I create a file .dmg for Mac application that users can download from our website? I have tried to create it, but users couldn't deploy my application because they didn't have certification.

Comment: That's got nothing to do with the `.dmg`.

Comment: Actually I wanna create file like skype.dmg 
http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-mac/downloading/